# my virtual-machine goes into standby

Tags: virtualbox

If not using virtual-box for 5 min, it goes automatically in standby. How do I increased the time for it to stay a bit longer. Is my VM goes into standby

Comment: What component "goes into standby"? The VM? The host OS?

Answer (score 0):

If you are in ubuntu you need to go to settings and power settings and change the settings there to never.

Comment: I try that and it didn't make any diffence